# Edit result of annotate in a Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have a queryset

```
queryset = BigTable.objects.values('field1__code', 'field2__code').annotate(Sum('field3'))
```

- the resulting value field3__sum = "1234567" is an integer and is very long for my template.
- How can I divide it by 1000 (for example) and get out it a decimal like "1234,5" ?
- Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the sum by 1'000 by wrapping this in a `Value(..)`:

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, Sum, Value

queryset = BigTable.objects.values(
    'field1__code', 'field2__code'
).annotate(
    field3_sum=Sum('field3', output_field=FloatField())/Value(1000, output_field=FloatField())
)
```

It might however be better to name your field *not* `field3_sum`, since that gives a wrong impression. Perhaps you can use `field3_sumdiv1000` for example.

In your template you can render with the [**`|floatformat`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat), for example:

```
{{ object.field3_sum|floatformat }}
```